# Running External Application( vlc player, text doc, .exe) using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i open a music file or a video file in VLC player or Window Media player by clicking a button on a webpage writter in HTML and JS.

Comment: You can't. The program which a file downloaded from a web browser is opened with is completely determined by the client OS at a lower level than JS has acces to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because it is managed by the client system. But... you could create a "pseudo protocol" in your system registry and assign it the VLC player.

For pseudo protocol I mean something like magnet torrent. ( magnet:?somedata )

Your pseudo protocol could be startvlc:yourdata.

Keep in mind that this operation must be done on all systems where you want to run your application.